# 外部から送られてきたメールが、メールサーバに着信する際の、ポート番号は？

Tags: mail

## 前提

レンタルサーバにメールサーバを置いて、自社から操作しています。自社のIPは特定できます。
このサーバでは、同サーバ内のPHPプログラムでメール送信し、不達メールを受信しています。

## 意図

不要・不審なアクセスは、ファイアウォールでポート番号で制限し、必要なアクセスは妨げたくないと考えています。

（制限したいアクセス）
(a)自メールサーバを使ってメール送信できるのは、自社からだけにしたい（IP制限）
(b)自メールサーバに到着したメールを参照できるのは、自社からだけにしたい（IP制限）

（塞ぎたくないアクセス）
(c)自メールサーバから、外部メールサーバに発信するメールは、送信したい
(d)外部メールサーバから、自メールサーバへ到着するメールは、着信したい

## 予定

上記(a)(b)に関して、次の通信を行うポート番号については、外部からアクセスできないよう、自社IP以外を制限する予定です。
・SMTP（SSLあり/なし）、POP3（SSLあり/なし）、IMAP（SSLあり/なし）

## 質問１

「予定」に書いた（外部からのアクセスを制限する）対策は、おそらく通常行われるものと想像しますが。

自サーバから外部へのアクセスは、通常制限しない、制限しない方がいい、と理解したらよいでしょうか？
塞いだら支障があるでしょうか？

## 質問２

上記(c)の通信は、アクセス先、外部メールサーバのポート番号何番を使って通信しますか？
上記(d)の通信は、アクセス先、自メールサーバのポート番号何番を使って通信しますか？
（これを塞がないことに留意したいため、正しく理解したく思います。）

## 質問２の補足

[メールはどうやって送っているのか、基本のしくみを知ろう | JAGAT](https://www.jagat.or.jp/mail_shikumi)

上記サイトの図を借りて説明すると、次の通信で使われるポート番号を知りたいと考えています。

> ４．メールサーバー【A】から送信先のメールアドレスを管理する
> 　　メールサーバー【B】に向けてメールを転送する

以上、よろしくお願いします。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 自分の理解を確固たるものにしたいので、まだクローズせずに、他の方の回答も拝見したく思います。

Answer (score 5):

> 自サーバから外部へのアクセスは、通常制限しない、制限しない方がいい、と理解したらよいでしょうか？
> 塞いだら支障があるでしょうか？

特段の理由がなければ制限する必要はないでしょう．最低限SMTP(TCP25)とDNS，あとは各種ソフト更新用にHTTP/Sが利用できれば問題ないかもしれませんが……．

> 上記(c)の通信は、アクセス先、外部メールサーバのポート番号何番を使って通信しますか？
> 上記(d)の通信は、アクセス先、自メールサーバのポート番号何番を使って通信しますか？

SMTPサーバー間の通信はいずれも原則TCP25宛の通信と考えて問題ないはずです．

Comment: 「SMTPサーバー間の通信はいずれも原則TCP25宛の通信と考えて問題ないはずです」とのこと、ありがとうございます。ということは、「予定」すなわち外部からのSMTPアクセス（25、他にも465、587）を塞ぐと、外部からのメールを受信できなくなると認識しました。（誤解してた場合、ご指摘いただければ幸いです）

Comment: teratailに[似たような要旨の質問](https://teratail.com/questions/25736#reply-40389)がありましたが、TCP25を塞ぐと原則外部からのメールは受信できなくなりますが、465/587はサブミッション用、すなわち認証を要求するクライアント(質問のaに該当)が使用するためのものとなるので夫妻でも問題ないはずです (過去の破棄された仕様を考えると厄介な話があるかもしれませんが気にする必要はありません)

Comment: 上の「意図」を実現するためには、「(a)→465/587は自社IP以外塞ぐ」「(c)(d)→25は塞がない」と理解しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

それぞれのプロトコルがどのポートを使うかは、基本的には仕様を見れば分かります。（他にも何かしらの歴史的経緯はあるかもしれませんが……。）

またこの話題については英語版 Wikipedia が良くまとまっていたため、一緒にリンクをつけています。

### SMTP

英語版 Wikipedia: [Simple Mail Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)（特に、[Ports の節](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Ports)）

- 25 番ポート：[RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) 4.5.4.2. Receiving Strategy が SMTP サーバーは 25 番ポートを listen しつづけると書いています。
- 465 番ポート：[RFC 8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314) 3.3. Implicit TLS for SMTP Submission が submissions サービスのために使われると書いています。また同じ節において SMTP サーバーとクライアントは 465 番ポートでの Implicit TLS を実装すべきと書いています。
- 587 番ポート：[RFC 8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314) 3.3. Implicit TLS for SMTP Submission が SMTP サーバーとクライアントは 587 番ポートでの STARTTLS を（移行期間の内は）実装すべきと書いています。

### POP3

英語版 Wikipedia: [Post Office Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol)

- 110 番ポート：[RFC 1939](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939) 3. Basic Operation が POP3 サーバーは 110 番ポートを listen すると書いています。
- 995 番ポート：[RFC 8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314) 3.1. Implicit TLS for POP が pop3s サービスのためにデフォルトでは 995 番ポートが使われると書いています。

### IMAP

英語版 Wikipedia: [Internet Message Access Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol)

- 143 番ポート：[RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) 2.1. Link Level が IMAP4rev1 サーバーは 143 番ポートを listen すると書いています。
- 993 番ポート：[RFC 8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314) 3.2. Implicit TLS for IMAP が imaps サービスのためにデフォルトでは 993 番ポートが使われると書いています。

Comment: 詳細な情報、ありがとうございます。各プロトコルのポート番号について、当方の認識と一致しており、（この点に当方に誤解はなかったと）安心しました。当方は、「"質問２の補足"の通信は、465/587ではなく、25である」というように、”現実にあてはめて解釈する”力が不足していたのだと思います。当方が何か誤解してそうでしたら、ご指摘いただけると幸いです。